# 403 Forbidden appears when deleting merge requests using the Gitlab API

Tags: api, gitlab, cicd, gitlab-runner

I would like to put the wrong sum and request closure.  After using the API's DELETE method, 403 appears and the personal token has been used。

```
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${TOKEN}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/merge_requests/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID}" -k
```

```
"message": "403 Forbidden"
```